# Safely 'print' raw html code in a textarea to use with CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Which character do I need to replace to safely 'print' raw HTML code from a database in a textarea, so I can edit this with CKeditor?

Or is there another existing preferred method of getting data into a CKeditor textarea? (e.g. AJAX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CKEditor will use the initial contents of the textarea, so all you need to do is escape it as you normally would, e.g.:

```
<textarea id="editor1">&lt;p&gt;My &lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt; text&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

See also [CKEDITOR.replace](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.replace).

If you want to set the contents of the textarea after CKEditor is loaded, use the [setData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData) API function:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('<p>This is the editor data.</p>');
```

In both cases, CKEditor will load the raw HTML and do whatever preprocessing is necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can now just take the variable that is returning the data from ajax or jquery and append it to the .setData(data).